# Can openx server just xml for a banner instead of adding html?

Tags: openx

I want to set up a zone in openx which will be invoked from a flash application, so I want openx to just serve back whatever xml I paste into the 'generic html banner'.  Problem is when I use the invocation code for the zone, openx is putting some html around the xml i specified.

Is there a way to get openx to return the xml without adding html around it?

Edit: The same problem occurs no matter what zone type you enter, openx wraps some extra text around it.  It appears what I want to achieve cannot currently be done with openx.

Comment: Did you try entering your XML as a simple text banner?

Comment: Yes, I tried text banner, the response builds the text using javascript and adds beacon calls.  Is there a way to make it return just the text without any javascript wrapping in the response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating, I have found there is no out of the box way to get openx to return the xml entered without modification.

Answer (score -2):

It might be possible using xml-rpc. However, if this is not a viable option, then you can consider creating a clone of the ajs.php file to only throw out banner content.